# Binding WPF datagrid to a List<List<object>>

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a List of Lists of Objects `List<List<object>>` and im wanting to bind it to a WPF datagrid programatically.

So far I have tried:

Code

```
dtgCores.ItemsSource = resinSystemData.data;
```

xaml

```
<DataGrid Name="dtgCores" Grid.Column="1">
```

But I just get 2 columns Capacity and Count. Could someone please advise?

I have a list of the column headers I would like to use in the format of a list aswell.

Please let me know if oyu need anymore information.

Comment: If you expect someone to answer this "question" you need to give more information than that. I.e how many lists are there, what kind of objects are in the list, what is your expected result, etc. There are also several other similar questions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bwpf%5D+binding+collection+of+collections)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A datagrid is not designed for this. It needs properties for its columns (hence Capacity and Count).

You'll need to choose:

- use another datastructure, like `List<SomeClass>`
- use another Control. A nested Listbox with 2 datatemplates will probably work.

Answer (score 3):

By default a `DataGrid` will bind columns to the properties of the objects in the immediate list it receives as the `ItemSource`. This is why when using a `List<List<object>>` as 'ItemSource', each line will show the two properties of a `List`, `Capacity` and `Count`.

You can however create your own `DataGridColumn` for each column and bind them to an index of the list. Here's is an example:

```
public void SetTestDataInGrid(List<List<object>> testData)
{
    testGrid.Columns.Clear();
    int colCount = testData.Max(x => x.Count);
    for (int i = 0; i < colCount; i++)
    {
        var currentColumn = new DataGridTextColumn();
        currentColumn.Binding = new Binding(string.Format("[{0}]", i));
        testGrid.Columns.Add(currentColumn);
    }
    testGrid.ItemsSource = testData;
}
```

This method checks the maximum length of the inner lists to determine the number of columns, and then creates a `DataGridTextColumn` for each column, binding each to the correct index of the inner list (`[0]`,`[1]`, etc.) and then sets the `ItemSource` to the `testData`.

You might want to also add `AutoGenerateColumns="False"` to the `DataGrid` to prevent creation of the `Capacity` and `Count` columns.